# Cannot add single line breaks in Questions

Tags: support, markdown, editor, list

I can't seem to add a simple line break in the text of my question (this is on Blender S.E. but happens on other communities as well):

[image]

What I am trying to do is make a list where each sentence is on a different line, using the `"RETURN"` key or `"RETURN"` + `"SHIFT".

Although the text editor displays the lines the way I want them, the text preview doesn't take into account this line break. There's always one more line break in the editor than there is in the preview.

I am using a iMac with Mac OS X Yosemite and Safari 9.0.3, a French Apple AZERTY extended keyboard.

Answer (score 6):

Why You don't use the list item included in the editor?

1. List item
2. List item
3. List item
4. List item

In Markdown, it looks like this:

```
 1. List item
 2. List item
 3. List item
 4. List item
```

It's important to include the period with a space after.

Also, you can add two spaces or a `<br/>` at the end of the line to include a break.

Check here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#linebreaks

Comment: Oh, ok! That seems like a possible option, thanks a lot! I just find it strange that pressing the line break key on my keyboard wouldn't work - to me that would be the simplest / most intuitive way to do this. And also the produced result when I type this key creates a visual difference between the editor and the preview, which I find weird and possibly a bug?

Comment: I also would like to see working as expected the shift+enter combination.... Hopefully your doubt is routed to the right person.... Might be she can help you, she's related to stackoverflow https://twitter.com/lauradobrzynski

Comment: @fabriced It is working as expected - the way Markdown specifies that it should be rendered. Markdown says to do a line break you need to add two spaces at the end of the line, or use `<br>` to break manually. Adding an extra break **does not** create a line break. It separates the text into two different paragraphs, and the space between the paragraphs can actually differ slightly from site to site.

Comment: Thanks for coming to the party @animuson

Comment: Also, you can add two spaces , correct

Answer (score 2):

To get a line break without a blank line, type <kbd>(space)</kbd><kbd>(space)</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> (or `<br>`<kbd>Enter</kbd>).

Comment: This doesn't work.  When I have a paragraph of text where I want to follow with a numbered list, if I `(space)(space)(enter)`, the list below collapses.

Comment: @TrippKinetics OK, I have no idea what you’re saying.  First of all, if you have a paragraph of text where you want to follow with a numbered list, you shouldn’t need to use this technique — just type Enter.  But I can’t reproduce the problem you’re describing.  Can you describe it more clearly? … … … P.S. This thread is over four years old.  Are you just trying this for the first time?  If it worked last month and it doesn’t work now, [it’s not my fault](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348746/195817 "We’re switching to CommonMark").

Comment: Nope, just trying this for the first time.  I mean I have a paragraph.  Immediately below the paragraph, I want a numbered list.  If I put a line break without two spaces, I get the list with a paragraph break in between.  If I put the line break including the spaces, the entire list collapses down into the paragraph text.

Comment: Well, as I said, I can’t reproduce that.  If you’re seeing this for the first time now, you should report it as a possible bug in the new CommonMark renderer.

Comment: Ok.  Thanks.  Will do.